# how to filter JSONArray from user input as intent?

Tags: android, json, android-intent

I'm using two activity . one for user input and another for display. 
i want to filter the JSONArray as user input in the first activity , I'm using Intent for this .
this is my 1st Activity.

```
 public class PlaceFinder extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.place_finder);
    }
  public void onClickplaceFinder(View view) {

    EditText UserPlace = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
 String UserPlaceText = UserPlace.getText().toString();


    Intent intent = new Intent(PlaceFinder.this , MainActivity.);
intent.putExtra("place", UserPlaceText);
     intent.putExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE,UserPlaceText);
startActivity(intent);
}
```

**and here goes my Second Activity JSON parse **

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public  static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "place";
        private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        private ListView lv;

        // URL to get contacts JSON
        private static String url = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/1an69r";

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> placeList;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);

 Intent intent = getIntent();
        String UserPlaceText = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        TextView UserPlace = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            placeList = new ArrayList<>();

            lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

            new GetPlace().execute();
        }

        /**
         * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
         */
        private class GetPlace extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                // Showing progress dialog
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Hope This To Work");
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();

            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

                // Making a request to url and getting response
                String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

                Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

                if (jsonStr != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                        // Getting JSON Array node
                        JSONArray places = jsonObj.getJSONArray("places");

                        // looping through All Contacts
                        for (int i = 0; i < places.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = places.getJSONObject(i);

                            String id = c.getString("id");
                            String name = c.getString("name");
                            String city = c.getString("city");
                            String needle = c.getString("needle");
                            String lat = c.getString("lat");
                            String lng = c.getString("lng");
                            String rating = c.getString("rating");
                            // Phone node is JSON Object


                            // tmp hash map for single contact
                            HashMap<String, String> place = new HashMap<>();

                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                            place.put("id", id);
                            place.put("name", name);
                            place.put("city", city);
                            place.put("needle", needle );
                            place.put("lat",lat);
                            place.put("lng",lng);
                            place.put("rating",rating);
                            // adding contact to place list
                            placeList.add(place);
                        }
                    } catch (final JSONException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                        .show();
                            }
                        });

                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });

                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                // Dismiss the progress dialog
                if (pDialog.isShowing())
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        MainActivity.this, placeList,
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"name", "city",
                        "lat","lng","needle","rating"}, new int[]{R.id.name,
                        R.id.city, R.id.lat,R.id.lng,R.id.needle,R.id.rating});

                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
    }
```

**LOG CAT**

```
I/art: Debugger is active
I/System.out: Debugger has connected
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: debugger has settled (1425)
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/tester.battleship-2/lib/arm
I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is tester.battleship, real application class is null.
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/tester.battleship-2/lib/arm
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: QUALCOMM Build: 10/21/15, 369a2ea, I96aee987eb
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0xa1f06980 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xa0ebf400
E/MainActivity: Response from url: {"mumbai":[{"id":1,"name":"place1","city":null,"needle":null,"lat":null,"lng":null,"rating":null,"created_at":"2017-06-26T02:57:43.617Z","updated_at":"2017-06-26T02:57:43.617Z"},{"id":2,"name":null,"city":"ranchi","needle":null,"lat":null,"lng":null,"rating":null,"created_at":"2017-06-26T02:57:43.763Z","updated_at":"2017-06-26T02:57:43.763Z"},{"id":3,"name":null,"city":null,"needle":"07301230AP","lat":null,"lng":null,"rating":null,"created_at":"2017-06-26T02:57:43.850Z","updated_at":"2017-06-26T02:57:43.850Z"},{"id":4,"name":null,"city":null,"needle":null,"lat":23.14,"lng":null,"rating":null,"created_at":"2017-06-26T02:57:43.953Z","updated_at":"2017-06-26T02:57:43.953Z"},{"id":5,"name":null,"city":null,"needle":null,"lat":null,"lng":85.3,"rating":null,"created_at":"2017-06-26T02:57:44.037Z","updated_at":"2017-06-26T02:57:44.037Z"},{"id":6,"name":null,"city":null,"needle":null,"lat":null,"lng":null,"rating":4,"created_at":"2017-06-26T02:57:44.129Z","updated_at":"2017-06-26T02:57:44.129Z"},{"id":7,"name":"place1","city":"ranchi","needle":"07301230AP","lat":23.14,"lng":85.3,"rating":4,"created_at":"2017-06-26T03:00:11.502Z","updated_at":"2017-06-26T03:00:11.502Z"},{"id":8,"name":"place1","city":"ranchi","needle":"07301230AP","lat":23.14,"lng":85.3,"rating":4,"created_at":"2017-06-26T03:01:44.261Z","updated_at":"2017-06-26T03:01:44.261Z"},{"id":9,"name":"place1","city":"ranchi","needle":"07301230AP","lat":23.14,"lng":85.3,"rating":4,"created_at":"2017-06-26T03:03:19.061Z","updated_at":"2017-06-26T03:03:19.061Z"},{"id":10,"name":"place2","city":"ranchi","needle":"07301430AP","lat":23.34,"lng":85.9,"rating":4,"created_at":"2017-06-26T03:03:19.183Z","updated_at":"2017-06-26T03:03:19.183Z"}],"places":[{"id":11,"name":"place3","city":"ranchi","needle":"09000130AP","lat":23.44,"lng":82.4,"rating":4,"created_at":"2017-06-26T03:03:19.283Z","updated_at":"2017-06-26T03:03:19.283Z"},{"id":12,"name":"place4","city":"ranchi","needle":"11301830AP","lat":23.54,"lng":87.3,"rating":4,"created_at":"2017-06-26T03:03:19.371Z","updated_at":"2017-06-26T03:03:19.371Z"},{"id":13,"name":"place5","city":"mumbai","needle":"10301930AP","lat":123.64,"lng":185.8,"rating":4,"created_at":"2017-06-26T03:03:19.459Z","updated_at":"2017-06-26T03:03:19.459Z"},{"id":14,"name":"place6","city":"patna","needle":"07301260AP","lat":173.34,"lng":485.3,"rating":4,"created_at":"2017-06-26T03:03:19.550Z","updated_at":"2017-06-26T03:03:19.550Z"},{"id":15,"name":"place7","city":"delhi","needle":"07301240AP","lat":383.34,"lng":485.3,"rating":4,"created_at":"2017-06-26T03:03:19.638Z","updated_at":"2017-06-26T03:03:19.638Z"}]}
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: tester.battleship, PID: 7622
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                      at tester.battleship.MainActivity$GetPlace.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:161)
                      at tester.battleship.MainActivity$GetPlace.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:59)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 7622 SIG: 9
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
```

Is there any method to this ? 
Thank You .

Comment: didn't understand your question. can you explain how do you want to filter your JSONArray

Comment: user will give an input and that input will be use as string in JSONArray(**) , through intent .

Comment: your question is not Understand as like your UserName....

Comment: You want to filter based on the name of the place in the JSONArray the user types?

Comment: @Omi i want to use  user input from 1st activity and through Intent i want to use in second activity (Json parse )  as as input in JSONArray ie jsonObj.getJSONArray("USer Input");

Comment: @EkundayoBlessingFunminiyi yes exactly :)

Comment: @EkundayoBlessingFunminiyi  yes I've tried and  the app keep crash

Comment: as I can see in your code you implemented Bundle to Intent in 1st Activity , is this work or not?

Comment: @Omi yeah that's working ..  app get crash after ProgressDialog appear

Comment: @sdfjklkjhgfdcvb then share app crash logcat..

Comment: @Omi just added ..

Comment: You are calling TextView UserPlace = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText); before  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main). You need to inflate your layout before you begin to find views

Answer (score 0):

First of all I strongly discourage you from using `asyncTasks` for your network calls. Try using a library like [Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit) for example.

BTW with this method you shoud lookup your list in onPostExecute before passing it to the adapter and filter it based on the string you passed as an Intent. Store the string as a field so you can access it around your class. Then make a method called something like `filterList()` that returns an `ArrayList<Places>`.
The method shoud iterate the list and compare the fields of the places object (I don't know WHICH fields you want to compare as you did not say it). Then simply remove irrelevant items and return the modified list. Then do what you did already: dismiss the dialog and pass the filtered list to the adapter.

Comment: shall i use Volley ??

Comment: I personally use Retrofit, but you can use volley!